# Set Up Medium Feed in React

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, gatsby

I'm trying to make a component that lists out my 3 recent posts on Medium. I want it to just list the title of the post and link out to the post.

So far I have the List Item component called `MediumItem` below is how I have it set up:

```
import React from 'react'
import { ExternalLink } from "react-feather"

const MediumItem = (props) => (
    <li><a href={props.url}>{props.title} <ExternalLink/></a></li>
)

export default MediumItem
```

And my feed is set up as follows:

```
import React from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import MediumItem from './mediumItem'
import { ExternalLink } from "react-feather"

class Medium extends React.Component {

    state = {
        posts: []
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchPosts().then(this.setPosts)
    }

    fetchPosts = () => axios.get(`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://us-central1-ryan-b-designs-medium-cors.cloudfunctions.net/medium?username=@RyanABrooks`)

    setPosts = ({data}) => {

        const { Post } = data.payload.references

        const posts = Object.values(Post).map(({ id, title, uniqueSlug}) => Object.assign({}, {
            title,
            url: `https://medium.com/@RyanABrooks/${uniqueSlug}`
        }))

        this.setState({
            posts
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h3>Recent Articles</h3>
                <ul>
                    { this.state.posts.map(({posts}, i) =>
                        <MediumItem key={i} {...posts} />
                    )}
                    <li><a href="https://medium.com/@RyanABrooks">Read More <ExternalLink /></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }

}

export default Medium
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how to pass the Title and URLs to the MediumItem components and make sure that it only lists the last 3 items.

Comment: FYI there's an official gatsby plugin to get data from medium: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-source-medium/

Answer (score 2):

Something like this perhaps:

```
render() {
  const last3 = this.state.posts.slice(-3);
  { last3.map((post, i) =>       // no need to use {posts} here
       <MediumItem key={i} title={post.title} url={post.url} />
  )}
}
```

That's assuming a structure for each post as:

```
{
  title: 'asdf',
  url: 'https://asdf'
}
```

Comment: This one is fine. But i feel like its better to explicitly say which props are u passing down instead of spreading data from api. Just for readability.

Comment: perhaps but it seemed like the OP wanted to use {...post} - changed anyhow

Comment: Yes, that solution was working and perfectly fine for most cases. I am just saying that in terms of readability it is better to explicitly say what is going on. Especially when there is no type hint like with typescript, flow or propTypes. (personal opinion)